# I have one project library path problem VS 2017

Tags: c#

I have some dll path problem for the class library I included in the solution.

Solution is a lot bigger than this so I can't put every here but the set up is similar to this.

ClassLib1 - generates classLib1.dll in /bin/Debug
ClassLib2 - generates classLib2.dll and referencing classLib1.dll to call some of function in the class1Lib1 class in /bin/Debug

ConsoleApp - Console Application project which calls a function in the class2 referencing only ClassLib2.dll

However when build the solution Class2Lib project is looking for ClassLib2.dll in /bin folder instead of /bin/debug. If I actually set up like this it works perfect and Classlib2 is always looking for ClassLib1.dll in /bin/debug folder but in my huge solution it looks for the ClassLib1 in /bin folder

What could be the reason why ClassLib2 is looking for ClassLib1 in the bin folder instead of /bin/debug?

Comment: Check output path in project properties - build for your class libs, than path in reference properties

Answer (score 0):

You should reference the project rather than their output dll's.

So:

`'ClassLib2' should reference project 'ClassLib1' (not dll).`

`'ConsoleApp' should reference project 'ClassLib1' and 'ClassLib2' (not dlls).`

Then it will work.